# "Invalid PID Sequence"

Tags: usb, usb-device, hid

I'm trying to create a HS USB device. The chirp sequence goes OK, but the device won't fullt enumerate. Device Manager reports "The request for the device descriptor failed". SO that's pretty clear I've got an issue there. However, I hooked up a protocol analyzer, and it's reporting "Invalid PID sequence errors" with each attempt. The User's Manual just says that means "An invalid sequence of packets has been observed". Is this really just a generic way to say bad device descriptor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, I had almost exactly the same issue, assumed Device didn't **ACK**ed, in your case it should be at index 2123 after DATA0.